# Como hacer un newsletter de este tipo?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Hola estoy haciendo una sección de blog para una pagina web, estoy batallando un poco con el diseño del newsletter porque no se como encuadrarlo bien, tengo un template ya definido pero necesito modificarlo según el diseño de la fotografía.El template ya tiene cargado bootstrap 3.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Volar | Blog Post</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Animation Libraries -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magic.min.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900%7COpen+Sans:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Fonts Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/et-line-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Owl Carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <!-- Nivo Lightbox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-lightbox/nivo-lightbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-lightbox/lightbox-theme.css">
    <!-- Animated Headlines -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animated-hedlines.css">
    <!-- Youtube Background Player -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/YTPlayer.css">
    <!-- Main Styles -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Theme -->
    <link href="css/theme/olive.css" rel="stylesheet" data-color="" id="theme">
    <!-- Animsition -->
    <link href="css/animsition.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Favicon (retina) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <meta name="application-name" content="&nbsp;" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mstile-144x144.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="page" class="animsition" data-animsition-in="fade-in" data-animsition-out="fade-out-up-sm" data-loader-type="loader1" data-page-loader-text="ESTUDIOJPG" style="transform-origin: 50% 50vh;">
        <!-- page-header -->
        <div class="page-header blog-post01-bg full-screen table overlay">
            <div class="table-cell">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row font-second">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 page-header-title-left font-second">
                            <h1 class="hs-text-12 init-animation-4 delay0-4s"><span>Un espacio en común, para crecer</span></h1>
                            <div class="hs-text-6 init-animation-4 delay0-6s">
                                LA CLAVE DEL FUTURO: APRENDER Y DESAPRENDER
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/ End col -->
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb text-right">
                                <li class="init-animation-3 delay1-0s"><a class="animsition-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                        <!--/ End col -->
                    </div>
                    <!--/ End row -->
                </div>
                <!--/ End container -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/ page-header -->
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <div class="position-relative">
            <!-- sticky: 1) add class="sticky-navbar" to #nav-wrapper | 2) remove navbar-fixed-top navbar-transparent class from #nav -->
            <div id="nav-wrapper" class="transp-nav">
                <nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-dark ripple-group-parent init-animation-2" role="navigation">
                    <!-- progressbar -->
                    <div id="scroll-progressbar" class="scroll-progressbar">
                        <div>
                            <span class="scroll-shadow"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container in-page-scroll">
                        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" id="animated-navicon" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mobile-navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand ripple-group" href="index.html#top">
                                <div class="navbar-logo pull-left">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x40" alt="logo" />
                                </div>
                                <p class="pull-left font-second">volar</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mobile-navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right cl-effect-5">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="ripple-group" href="index.html#top">
                                        <span data-hover="Inicio">Inicio</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="ripple-group" href="index.html#Estudio-section">
                                        <span data-hover="Estudio">Estudio</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="ripple-group" href="index.html#portfolio-section">
                                        <span data-hover="Portfolio">Portfolio</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="ripple-group animsition-link" href="blog.html">
                                        <span data-hover="Blog">Blog</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="ripple-group" href="index.html#Contacto-section">
                                        <span data-hover="Contacto">Contacto</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container -->
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/ End Navbar -->
        <!-- Do not remove the div below if you want to a sticky navbar! -->
        <div id="about-section"></div>
        <!-- section -->
        <div class="section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-9 padding-right-sm-50">
                        <!-- Post -->
                        <section class="blog-post">
                            <!-- Post Media -->
                            <div class="blog-page-media">
                                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Post Title -->
                            <h1 class="blog-page-post-title font-second"><span>Como diseñar mi estrategia </span>en redes sociales</h1>
                            <!-- Date, Author, Categories, Comments -->
                            <div class="blog-item-detail no-margin-left">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> john doe</a>
                                <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> <a href="#" class="no-padding-right">photography </a>,<a href="#"> minimal</a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> 2 comments</a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Post body text -->
                            <div class="blog-item-body">
                                <p>
                                    Fusce non ante sed lorem rutrum feugiat. Vestibulum pellentesque, purus ut&nbsp;dignissim consectetur, nulla erat ultrices purus, ut&nbsp;consequat sem elit non sem. Morbi lacus massa, euismod ut turpis molestie, tristique sodales est. Integer sit amet mi id sapien tempor molestie in nec massa. Fusce non ante sed lorem rutrum feugiat.
                                </p>
                                <blockquote>
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a&nbsp;ante.
                                    </p>

                                </blockquote>
                                
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia a cum porro. Quasi possimus fugit eum impedit cumque qui, rerum nostrum laborum, consequatur dolorum. Libero, quasi iusto enim recusandae veritatis.</p>
                            </div>
                            <!--/ End Post body text -->
                            <div class="tags">
                                <a href="">Design</a>
                                <a href="">Photography</a>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        <!--/ End Post -->
                        <nav class="article-nav row">
                            <a href="#ignore-click" class="article-nav-link col-sm-6">
                                <i class="ci-icon-uniE893"></i>
                                <p>A kurdish breakfast
                                    <br /><span class="post-date">martch 23, 2015</span></p>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#ignore-click" class="article-nav-link col-sm-6">
                                    <p>a letter to momo
                                        <br /> <span class="post-date">may 12, 2015</span></p>
                                        <i class="ci-icon-uniE890"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </nav>
                                <!-- Comments -->
                                <section class="blog-comment-section">
                                    <ul class="media-list text comment-list clearlist">
                                        <!-- Comment Item -->
                                        <li class="media comment-item">
                                            <a class="pull-left" href="#"><i class="comment-avatar fa fa-user"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="media-body">
                                                <div class="comment-item-data">
                                                    <div class="comment-author">
                                                        <a href="#">John Doe</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    May 7, 21:12
                                                </div>
                                                <p>
                                                    Soluta recusandae impedit aliquid voluptate quaerat. Beatae, quaerat? Natus dignissimos quibusdam repudiandae placeat saepe, numquam, ab unde minima amet blanditiis tempora. Perferendis.
                                                </p>
                                                <a href="#" class="comment-reply"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>&nbsp;Reply</a>
                                                <!-- Comment of second level -->
                                                <div class="media comment-item">
                                                    <a class="pull-left" href="#"><img class="media-object comment-avatar" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" width="50" height="50">
                                                    </a>
                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                        <div class="comment-item-data">
                                                            <div class="comment-author">
                                                                <a href="#">Tora Pritt</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                            May 7, 21:12
                                                        </div>
                                                        <p>
                                                            Neque, praesentium atque repudiandae! Quaerat provident vero in consequuntur. Autem praesentium amet reiciendis iure, unde, aliquam beatae nihil libero, necessitatibus provident suscipit.
                                                        </p>
                                                        <a href="#" class="comment-reply"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>&nbsp;Reply</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- End Comment of second level -->
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <!-- End Comment Item -->
                                        <!-- Comment Item -->
                                        <li class="media comment-item">
                                            <a class="pull-left" href="#"><i class=" comment-avatar fa fa-user"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="media-body">
                                                <div class="comment-item-data">
                                                    <div class="comment-author">
                                                        <a href="#">Angela Cora</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    May 7, 21:12
                                                </div>
                                                <p>
                                                    Tuis quam ipsum exercitationem iure vel error non voluptatum corporis culpa. Laudantium voluptatem magnam quasi soluta, fuga eum minima id architecto porro.
                                                </p>
                                                <a href="#" class="comment-reply"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>&nbsp;Reply</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <!-- End Comment Item -->
                                    </ul>
                                </section>
                                <!-- End Comments -->
                                <!-- Add Comment -->
                                <section class="blog-comment-section">
                                    <h2 class="blog-page-post-title font-second margin-bottom-60">Leave a reply</h2>
                                    <!-- Form -->
                                    <form id="ajax-contact" class="" method="post" action="mailer.php">
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <!--/ End from messages -->
                                                <div class="input col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padding-bottom-xs-50 padding-bottom-40">
                                                    <label class="input-label" for="name">
                                                        <span class="input-label-content font-second" data-content="name">name *</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <input class="input-field" type="text" name="name" id="name" required />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="input col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padding-bottom-xs-50 padding-bottom-40">
                                                    <label class="input-label" for="company">
                                                        <span class="input-label-content font-second" data-content="company">company</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <input class="input-field" type="text" name="company" id="company" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="input col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padding-bottom-xs-50 padding-bottom-40">
                                                    <label class="input-label" for="email">
                                                        <span class="input-label-content font-second" data-content="email">email *</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <input class="input-field" type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row margin-bottom-20 margin-top-xs-10">
                                                <div class="message col-xs-12 ">
                                                    <label class="textarea-label font-second" for="message">message *</label>
                                                    <textarea class="input-field textarea" name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 padding-top-sm-20 padding-top-xs-10 text-left">
                                                    <button id="btn-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-animated btn-contact ripple-alone" data-text="send it"><span class="btn-icon"><span class="loader-parent"><span class="loader2"></span></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 padding-top-sm-20 padding-top-xs-10">
                                                <div id="form-messages" class="form-message"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                                <!-- End Form -->
                            </section>
                            <!-- End Add Comment -->
                            <div id="end-content"></div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/ End col -->
                        <div id="sidebar" class="col-sm-3 sidebar">
                            <div class="widget">
                                <form class="" role="form">
                                    <div class="search-wrap">
                                        <button class="search-button" type="submit" title="Start Search">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <input type="text" class="input-field " placeholder="Search...">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <!--/ End widget search -->
                            <div class="widget widget-text">
                                <h3 class="widget-title font-awesome">Quiero comunicarme por:</h3>
                                <a class="widget-title font-second" href="#">Zoom</a>
                                <a class="widget-title font-second" href="#">Whatsapp</a>
                                <a class="widget-title font-second" href="#">Mail</a>
                            </div>
                            <!--/ End widget-text -->
                            <div class="widget widget-posts-recent">



                                <h4 class="widget-title font-second">Coordinar reunión</h4>
                                <h4 class="widget-title font-awesome">Quiero saber cuando se publique un nuevo post</h4>
                                <div class="widget-body">

                                    <!--Newsletter -->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 padding-bottom-xs-50 padding-bottom-40">
                                            <input class="input-field" type="text" name="name" id="name" required />
                                            <label class="input-label" for="name">
                                                <span class="input-label-content font-second">Nombre</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 padding-bottom-xs-50 padding-bottom-40">
                                            <input class="input-field" type="text" name="correo" id="correo" required />
                                            <label class="input-label" for="correo">
                                                <span class="input-label-content font-second">Correo</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/ End widget-recent-posts -->
                            
                            <!--/ End widget-categories -->
                        </div>
                        <!--/ End col -->
                    </div>
                    <!--/ End row -->
                </div>
                <!--/ End container -->
            </div>
            <!--/ End section -->
            <footer class="footer-section section no-padding-bottom ">
                <div class="footer-logo">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x40" alt="logo" />
                    <p class="font-second">
                        volar
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-social">
                    <a href="#." class="fa fa-facebook-square wow fadeIn" data-wow-offset="150" data-wow-delay="0s"></a>
                    <a href="#." class="fa fa-twitter wow fadeIn" data-wow-offset="150" data-wow-delay=".15s"></a>
                    <a href="#." class="fa fa-google-plus wow fadeIn" data-wow-offset="150" data-wow-delay=".3s"></a>
                    <a href="#." class="fa fa-pinterest wow fadeIn" data-wow-offset="150" data-wow-delay=".45s"></a>
                    <a href="#." class="fa fa-youtube-play wow fadeIn" data-wow-offset="150" data-wow-delay=".6s"></a>
                </div>
                <div id="go-top" class="go-top go-top-out in-page-scroll">
                    <div class="circle1"></div>
                    <a href="#top" class="square"><span></span></a>
                    <div class="rectangle"></div>
                    <div class="circle2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-bottom">
                    <!-- Copyright -->
                    <a class="footer-bottom-text font-second" href="http://themeforest.net/item/volar-one-page-parallax-template/11698815" target="_blank">Volar © 2015. All Right Reserved.</a>
                    <!-- End Copyright -->
                </div>
            </footer>
            <!--/ End Footer Section -->
        </div>
        <!-- JS Scripts -->
        <script src="js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="js/jquery.animsition.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="js/animateSlider.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="js/animated-headlines.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="js/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="js/jquery.vide.min.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="js/jquery.particleground.min.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="js/fss.min.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="js/fssinit.js"></script> -->
        <script src="js/retina.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="js/nivo-lightbox.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="js/contactForm.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> -->
        <script src="js/scripts.min.js"></script>
        <!--/ End JS Scripts -->
    </body>

    </html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias dejar bien en claro donde esta tu problema? esa es una pagina entera y no se entiende cual es el problema...

Comment: Basicamente no se como hacer para que el label quede debajo del input como se muestra en la imagen

Comment: Entonces por favor circunscribe tu pregunta a eso.. muestra tu css si tenes y no pongas todo el resto de las cosas... Tambien, te fijaste como era el css en esa pagina?